# javascript library using rellax.js

Tags: javascript

I'm implementing a basic usage of the relax js library.

https://github.com/dixonandmoe/rellax

My test is here:
https://rellax.superhi.com/

My code follows the example on github and is working for me now.

I'm calling the libary via

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rellax/1.6.2/rellax.min.js">
    </script>
```

html is:

```
      <div class="rellax">
  I’m that default chill speed of "-2"
</div>
<div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="7">
  I’m super fast!!
 </div>
 <div class="rellax" data-rellax-speed="-4">
   I’m extra slow and smooth
  </div>


  // Accepts any class name
  var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');
```

I needed to provide the instantiation above that @Xufox helped with.

Comment: Are you really writing `<scriptsrc="`…`">` instead of `<script src="`…`">` and missing the `>` at the first `<div>`?

Comment: sorry.  i think I just formatted post incorrectly @Xufox

Comment: So, now everything works just fine, right? “not working” is a meaningless phrase. Have you read the docs? Where is your `new Rellax` instantiation?

Comment: I added an instantiation and made some edits to the question.  @Xufox

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: sorry i had to remove the <script> tags and now its working thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to provide the instantiation above that @Xufox helped with.

// Accepts any class name
  var rellax = new Rellax('.rellax');